# Xcode show contact card (contacts app)

Tags: iphone, xcode, hyperlink, contacts

I didn't find any solution so far.
I am trying to link to the "Contacts" app from apple.
For example I have a Firstname and a Lastname and maybe a phone number is it than possible to show with this information the matching "contact card" in contacts? So my app should open the Contacts app and show the "contact card" from this person where I have the First- and Lastname in my app. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

NO, there is no URL Scheme top open the contacts app.

You can use the SDK to directly interacte with the contact on the users device.
Have a at the [AddressBook](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=AddressBook) API documentation.

Comment: ok thanks for the fast reply! hoped for better news but okay.. I know the AddressBook API a little but hoped to open the contacts app with a person like the maps app with coordinates...too bad...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AddressBook framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/_index.html) if it suits your need.